# 500 Internal Server Error In Load Testing By Jmeter for SAP application

Tags: jmeter, sap, internal-server-error, http-status-code-500

I am writing load test script for an SAP-based application in jmeter. I am getting 500 internal Server.

I saw that the request looks same which I have on the browser network tab and the one I provided in JMeter. The only difference is in the request header, that I am not providing any SAP-passport in my request. I am not to see the SAP-Passport in the response of any previous request's response so that I can extract that and use in future requests.

Please tell me if I am assuming correctly that the SAP-Passport is the issue, if yes then how can I get that and use in the request. Also if there is a way to get any static SAP-Passport.

Its a blocker for me and its on priority, please help.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see from [Single Sign-On with SAP Passports](https://support.sap.com/en/my-support/single-sign-on-passports.html) article it is a matter of adding a client certificate to JMeter.

1. Obtain SAP Passport root certificate somehow (i.e. export it from your browser)
2. Add it to JMeter. This can be done in 2 ways:

   - Using [SSL Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SSL_Manager)
   - Using JMeter *system.properties* file

Check out [How to Set Your JMeter Load Test to Use Client Side Certificates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-set-your-jmeter-load-test-use-client-side-certificates) guide for comprehensive instructions on both approaches.

Comment: I am not able to get certificate yet, but trying more

Comment: I got the certificate and tried the way you shared, but it didn't work